# Computer automatically shuts down after a period of idling

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, reboot

My computer running Windows 7 suddenly starts behaving very strangely. If I leave it idled for a while, it automatically logs off and restarts. After that, it may or may not restart successfully. What I mean by that is that when the manufacturer's logo appears when booting, it shuts down and restarts again.

I don't know if this is a hardware or software issue. Does anyone have a clue of what's going on? I know what I am describing here is vague, but that's all I can provide.

Comment: Have you checked for a virus?

Comment: Could be hardware, but it is interesting that it only happens when idle.  It is possible the power management is switching something off that is breaking things, so it reboots to recover.  Check the event logs (Start, then type 'event viewer' in the search box.

Comment: Are you sure it is not installing Windows updates and then reboots automatically? See in the "Installed Windows Updates" under control panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a desktop, try replacing the USB keyboard. Bizarre as it may sound, I had a similar problem and noticed a bit of odd non-responsiveness in the keyboard while in the BIOS of the ailing machine. After checking the usual hardware stuff as a last resort I changed the keyboard. All symptoms ceased.